# Using Java to insert into mySql

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert some stuff into a sql database but my code isn't working. I'm kinda new to this, but after trying a few different things I am still stuck. Any ideas as to how I could get my code to work? I'm not actually getting any errors, but the information is never entered into the database. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class sqlIns
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tempdatat";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "Nathan1";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user, pass);
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert Into tempdata(id, timedata, tempdata) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            statement.setInt(1, 1);
            statement.setInt(2, 30);
            statement.setDouble(3, 78.30);
            statement.execute();
            statement.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
                 System.out.println("Done!");
        }

     }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted. Is it printing "Done!"?

Comment: you should ensure `con` and `statement` are always closed

Comment: @RC. Huh? Yes, you should close statements as a matter of good practice and he also closes the connection. THe only improvement would be to move the scoping and do it in the `finally` block

Comment: @Brian, oops I missed the statement line, but yeah, this should go in the `finally`

Comment: I faced the same problem but with MS Access not MySQL, `con.setAutoCommit(false)` before executing the query and `con.setautocommit(true)` after executing solved my problem.

Comment: @Brian. It is printing done, but its not actually inserting into that database when I go back and check.

Comment: @RC. I added that part to the finally block. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Your DB table names are different in your **host** variable & **sql query**. Make sure of correct table name of database at both places. And, Use all lowercase letters for sql query.

Try it:

```
insert into tempdata(id, timedata, tempdata) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Instead of :

```
Insert Into tempdata(id, timedata, tempdata) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is actually pretty good, and you almost got it right.

Your only mistake is that for INSERT you need to use:

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What is the problem with `execute()` ?

Comment: @CostisAivalis No, it doesn't. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute() - there is nothing wrong with the OP's code as written.

Comment: @CostisAivalis Linking to something the OP isn't using ... really doesn't change anything. Try looking at the JavaDoc for `PreparedStatement`

Comment: You are right! I thought it was a Statement. I did not look well into the code.